# Avoiding the `npm login` (`npm adduser') email prompt in npm & jFrog artifactory

Tags: login, prompt, npm, jfrog

When I do `npm login` (alias of `npm adduser`) I ALWAYS get prompted for my email address.

```
Username: ...
Password: ...
Email: (this IS public) ...
```

This is obnoxious.  I've done `npm config -g set email ...` and confirmed that it sticks.  I've confirmed that my git config has `user.email` accurately, in case npm would try to pull from there.

Is there any way to suppress that prompt?  I'm logging into jFrog, but I think they're just mimicking npm registry behavior here.